# Getting submit type to post its value

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, post

I am trying to get the value of my button to be sent along with the form post, currently I have:

```
  <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="getData">
       <h1>Quick Query</h1>
        <div class="floating-placeholder">
            <input id="origin" name="origin" type="text" placeholder="Number" value="5"/>
            <label for="origin"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="floating-placeholder">
            <input id="destination" name="destination" type="text" placeholder="Number" value="4"/>
            <label for="destination"></label>
        </div>

        <label>
            <input type="submit" name="submitDriving" id="submitDriving" value="driving"/>

            <input type="submit" name="submitTransit" id="submitTransit" value="transit" />
            <input type="submit" name="submitCycling" id="submitCycling" value="cycling" />
        </label>
    </form>
```

the current post has

```
{ origin: '5',
  destination: '4' }
```

I am trying to get a away where if the submitDriving button is clicked the POST made is:

```
{ origin: '5',
  destination: '4',
  submitDriving: 'driving' }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. It works as you want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users would expect something more like the following with a SELECT and a single button to submit the form. This is a keep it simple approach.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="getData">
       <h1>Quick Query</h1>
        <div class="floating-placeholder">
            <input id="origin" name="origin" type="text" placeholder="Number" value="5"/>
            <label for="origin"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="floating-placeholder">
            <input id="destination" name="destination" type="text" placeholder="Number" value="4"/>
            <label for="destination"></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <select name="transitType" id="transitType">
              <option>drive</option>
              <option>cycling</option>
              <option>transit</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <label>
            <input type="submit" />
         </label>
    </form>
```

You can accomplish your original question with javascript and listening to the onsubmit event of the form. But it really breaks standard UI which users expect to see.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there no way to use 3 separate boxes vs having the user use the drop down?